# Need clarity on using django-rest-framework-jwt with django-rest-auth for social login

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, django-rest-framework-jwt

I am able to receive a facebook authentication access_token from `django-rest-auth` by following their [instructions in their docs](http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#social-authentication-optional), but it doesn't look like it's a JWT token generated by `django-rest-framework-jwt`.
I did set `REST_USE_JWT = True` in `settings.py`. That's all I've done, I'm not sure if there's anything else I need to do to ensure that the token is being generated by JWT.
I set up an endpoint to verify a jwt token like so:

```
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token, verify_jwt_token
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^api/token-verify/', verify_jwt_token),
]
```

that's how I'm testing if the access token received by this endpoint

```
url(r'^rest-auth/facebook/$', views.FacebookLogin.as_view(), name='fb_login'),
```

is a valid JWT token. When I try to verify the token I get an error `Error decoding signature`.

On a side note, I noticed when I try to do a `POST` request to `rest-auth/facebook/` API endpoint twice using the same `access_token` returned by a Facebook login I am receiving a `403 Forbidden` from django.

Can someone please explain a bit how to make JWT work with django-rest-auth?

Comment: Did you solve it or did you change your workflow?

Comment: I ditched jwt and instead used Django allauth with token authentication

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I must use JWT. This lib: https://github.com/st4lk/django-rest-social-auth supports JWT. Seeing if it could be useful for my workflow.